# Could I make a machine that runs on dirt?

Tags: mass-energy

This may sound really stupid, but all matter can be converted into energy. So couldn't it be possible to build like an engine that you'd fill up with dirt and it would run. I understand they're would be a lot of energy loss if something like this was possible. However if it's not possible could you explain why?

Comment: Matter can not be converted to energy. That's just a common misconception that has established itself due to endless but utterly imprecise repetitions of the relativistic mass-energy equivalence. In reality it's a thermodynamics problem, as with any other machine. _If_ you had a zero temperature bath and _if_ black holes radiate Hawking radiation without any preservation of lepton number etc., then you could convert arbitrary matter into radiation (which is _not_ energy but merely a massless quantum field, whereas matter is massive fields).  But all of these are big ifs.

Comment: @CuriousOne well said. Washington you are referring to mass energy equivalence but it just shows how much energy is stored in the mass M and how much mass is in a EM field of energy E. However you can not just pass the barrier from mass to energy. Energy from mass is known as nuclear energy. There are two methods to do this 1) nuclear fission as in nuclear reactors and 2) nuclear fusion as in stars and some research is going on earth. Even if you think that mass comes from energy, you can see mass because it is in lower energy state than its earlier form.

Comment: I understand that mass can't always be converted into energy, but why can't dirt be converted into energy the same way gasoline or coal can?

Comment: A fraction of a percent efficiency can be had by fusion of the light elements in dirt (H, C, O, Si, Na...) if you have a very large star to do the job.   Our solar system doesn't have one that big...

Comment: @Washington Because dirt doesn't have the same chemistry as gasoline or coal. You can't plant a successful garden in gasoline, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [uranium ore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_ore) is a form of dirt, and with a suitable processing does 
give out energy at the cost of its weight in mass.

The machines invented are [called reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal-neutron_reactor), quite complicated though, one needs:

> Neutron moderator to slow down the neutrons. In light water reactors and heavy water reactors it doubles as the nuclear reactor coolant.
>
> Nuclear fuel, which is a fissile material, usually uranium.

The process of purifying the [nuclear fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fuel) is quite laborious too.

> Reactor vessel that is a pressure vessel containing the coolant and reactor core.
>
> Radiation shielding to protect people and the environment from the harmful effects of ionizing radiation.
>
> Containment buildings which is designed, in any emergency, to contain the escape of radiation.
>
> Instrumentation to monitor and control the reactor's systems.

So yes, machines are being used to provide part of your electricity , which turn dirt into energy. It is possible to convert part of dirt into electrical energy, but it is very complicated.

I want to address your:

> However if it's not possible could you explain why?

Matter comes in elements seen at the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) of elements. These elements are composites of protons and neutrons  bound into a nucleus and the atoms have electrons caught in the proton fields so they are neutral. Most of the mass resides in the nucleus, and the protons and neutrons are bound inside it. In the same way that to get energy from a water fall, the water has to be at a higher level than where the hydroelectric system is, in order to get nuclear energy a nucleus has to be at a higher energy unstable  level so as to release energy by breaking up to lower mass nuclei. Most of the elements found in dirt are at their stable configuration. Unstable isotopes ( same number of charges but different mass) exist but few of them offer to possibility of as sustained reaction to lower energy states. One of them is [uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission).

So it is possible but due to the complexity of utilizing the properties,it cannot be a home construction, not even a university lab construction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we should not forget about the dirt machine millions/billions of year old where stuff grows in dirt, you get wood, burn it and get energy. Although there are other ingredients like seeds, water and sunlight.

This can be considered a machine because, there is a biochemical mechanism at work.

Therefore, if this process can be fine tuned, and sped up, possibly a dirt machine is possible at some level.

Comment: Good, this utilizes the other stored energy, electromagnetic energy.